# Homebrew: How to "unlink" an app cask?

Tags: homebrew

I know app artifacts are installed into `/Applications` directly.

And I spot below output when uninstalling Dropbox:

```
==> Backing App 'Dropbox.app' up to '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/dropbox/140.4.1951/Dropbox.app'
```

an intermediate step of uninstalling but exactly what I want.

So does there exist a fine-grained command for this and a reverse counterpart?

Just like I can brew *link* & *unlink* a formula?

Answer (score 1):

> So does there exist a fine-grained command for this and a reverse counterpart?

Unfortunately, there isn't a native way of doing this in homebrew cask. From a [similar feature request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/29870#issuecomment-277554334):

> We used to link. It doesn’t work and only leads to problems. Most users prefer it this way.

<del>A kind of hacky way would be to delete it from `/Applications` when you don't need it, and copy it over from `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/` when you do.</del>  Thanks to @nichijou for clarifying this isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think you can bring it back by copying from _Caskroom_, There hold only symlinks.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for clarifying. I'll update that accordingly. I guess it's either you have it installed or you don't. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`